# Django, unable to start on local:host

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using `dj4e` in *pythonanywhere.com*, I am trying to start the project but it gives an error saying that `port 8000` is already in use. I tried to run from another port but nothing.

> In `dj4e's` document, it says I can't use `"runserver"` command in
> `virtualenv`.

Could somebody help me running the local server, please?

Comment: hi try this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4c4ickks2A&ab_channel=PrettyPrinted

Comment: You don't use runserver on prod, it's a development only server

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your web app to run it on PythonAnywhere. `runserver` would not work there. You may follow https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/